# How to focus table row?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to set focus on the last row in my table when the user presses cmd+rightarrow. The user should in that way be able to choose any row element out of 8 without using a mouse.
The keybinding works perfectly (and event listeners are added), but there is something wrong with the refs.

```
const selRef = useRef<any>();

const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && ['ArrowRight'].includes(e.key)) {
        selRef.current.focus();
    }

return (
                    <tbody>
                        {value.map((trip, index) => (
                            <div>
                                <tr
                                    onClick={() =>
                                        props.onSelect(trip, 'copy')
                                    }
                                    key={`history-row-${index}`}
                                    className={styles.focused}
                                    ref={selRef}
                                >
                                    <td id="sr-td-shortcut">{index + 1}</td>
                                    <td id="sr-td-pick">
                                        {genFormattedAddress(trip.start)}
                                    </td>
                                    <td id="sr-td-drop">
                                        {genFormattedAddress(trip.end)}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
    )
```

Comment: You need to console.log the selfRef, as I think it is refering only the last tr in list.

Comment: @Mohindersingh That is correct, but this does not focus it either. I don't understand why the focusing does not work.

Comment: can u share your styles.foucsed here.

Comment: @Mohindersingh It just changes the background color red. 
`.focused:focus {
    background-color: red !important;
}`

Comment: Can u check on browser by focusing it. Is it taking color red or not.
Open devConsole and click on :hov in styles and then use focus.

Comment: or You can try giving onFocus on your tr and console.log the index.
onFocus={()=>console.log(index)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` elements can not accepts focus by default. To enable focus behaviour, add `tabindex={0}` on `<tr>`

Comment: Thank you! This was the main issue and I was able to solve the problem!